# Handle custom exceptions using @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a class that catches exceptions using the Spring annotation @ExceptionHandler and this class support some custom exceptions as well. I would like that when I raise the exception `CustomRuntimeException` in this way `throw new CustomRuntimeException(args...);`, it will be caught and handled in the following method:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CutomExceptionManager {

    // code
    
    @ExceptionHandler({CustomRuntimeException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    private ResponseEntity<ErrorResource> handleCustomException(CustomException e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.error("unhandled exception: ", (Exception)e);
        
        // other code
    }
    
}
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: nothing seems wrong with the code, it could be a scanning issue.
just to be sure - CustomException extends Exception? try also writing the same class in the annotation and in the signature (replace CustomException with CustomRuntimeException)
try writing in the annotation value = {CustomRuntimeException.class} (that works in my code, just to make sure)
what package is this class in? are you sure its being scanned by Spring?

Comment: also, why is the method private? try making the method public or protected

Comment: Yes @TomElias, CustomException extends RuntimeException

Comment: @TomElias about CutomExceptionManager class, it's part of a custom package that I'm using as a library.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Tom Elias, the method should be `protected` or `public` to be taken in account by Spring.

As an example, the following code is working.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ControllerException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ControllerException> handleControllerException(ControllerException controllerException) {
    log.error(controllerException.getFullMessage(), controllerException);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(controllerException, HttpStatus.valueOf(controllerException.getStatus()));
}
```

BTW, no need to add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to the method.